React Native WebView App Crashes When Changing Profile
I am developing a React Native application that uses WebView to display web content. The app works fine during development and testing, but it crashes when I change the profile in the version downloaded from the App Store. Here is the code snippet for the WebView implementation:
I use the WebView component to load a URL (https://www.weedx.io/), and it displays correctly. However, when the user changes their profile, the app crashes. I've tried several approaches to handle this, but nothing seems to work

Please explain your question in detail. What do you mean by changing profiles?, is it similar to switching between multiple accounts like we do in Instagram?

After logging in to our app, it crashes when the user attempts to change their profile using the camera. This issue only occurs on iOS devices; it works fine on Android

You mean uploading profile picture using camera?
